# Fixing the size?

Tags: java, 2d, android, graphics

My app isn't compatible with all screen sizes. When testing on a small size, my textview overlaps with my button. So, as suggested on the Android Documentation, and **many** stack overflow pages, I created a new `Android Resource Directory`:

[image: Directories]

In my `layout-small,` I copy and pasted one of the xml layouts of a layout that was overlapping in small screen size. So now, it looks like this:

[image]

My layout, `activity_finished_before_timer.xml`, was just copied from the regular layout to the small layout. Now, in my manifest, I specified the following. I don't know if this is necessary, but after spending hours online searching for the answer, I added it just in case:

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

After doing **everything** I could find for **hours and hours,** the layout is still overlapping. By overlapping, I mean that my textview is under my button on a small screen. It looks fine on a regular screen though.

**I have got some advice** to do something where I create a layout resource file, but instead of titling the resource file as `layout-small`, I should title it with the dp size at which my app stops working:

`layout-swp365dp`

This would mean  (**In coding terms:**)

```
if (screen size > 365dp) use default;
else use default-adjusted.
```

Now, how do I get the screen size then? On my emulator, the size is given like this:

[image]

How do I get the size in `dp` then? For this method, I would just need to hit and try different screen sizes until I find the one that doesn't work. How do I do that? Is there an easier way?

**So, now I am lost** I would really appreciate **any** feedback on how to resolve this issue of why the layout is **still** being overlapped. It is very odd, since I have done everything I needed to according to all of the sources I looked at. Please help me in figuring out how to make my layout flexible enough for multiple screen sizes. Although I am frustrated at this issue, I am more eager to learn out of it, as it is my first android game.

Comment: Show your xml layout file. I am pretty sure you messed it up...

Answer (score -1):

The smart thing to do would be to create a method, like getScreenRes
to get the screen resolution in pixels.

```
private static int WIDTH = 1280;
private static int HEIGHT = 720;

public static void createDisplay() {



    try {
    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT)); //Use your code, but change these variables!
    Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
    Display.setTitle("Aincrad Online ALPHAV.4.1");
    } catch(LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Use the method you created to get the screen resolution to change the WIDTH and HEIGHT variables in the code. Of course, you should translate all the code to the language you are using

Comment: This does not answer the question at all... OP doesn't know how to get screen resolution and saying "create a method for it" without providing the method body is useless.